# Can I rely on ETags for cache control

Tags: javascript, http, caching, requirejs, browser-cache

Our current deployment uses a home build cache busting approach: We have mapping file that contains hashes of our javascript files (this mapping is created on application startup). The values in this file are then used in our templates to generate a script tag that includes a GET parameter for cache busting i.e `<script src="/static/js/somefile?v=adg34d>`

I'm currently converting our entire page to use RequireJS and I would like to get rid of these cache busting parameters since they would be difficult to implement. Our HTTP servers are configured to add a correct `Last-Modified` and `ETag` header to each asset resource they serve. If I look at the Chrome Web Console I can see that the browser also uses it and gets a correct `304`. While I trust Chrome to get this right there are of course other browsers.

**The question is**: If I only use `Last-Modified` and `ETag` headers can rely on the browser to get it right or do I really *need* a cache-busting parameter?

I only need to support:

- Opera
- Firefox
- Chrome
- IE >= 8
- Safari >= 5

Comment: With your origional approach, the url is different, and you could cache it indefinately knowing that if its changed the url would change, with etags you will have to always do a 304 check to verify.

If your current method uses 304's also nothing will change, and then yes using ETags works as described, however, since the requests are async the browser will resolve to cache often. Eventually it will refresh (like reopening your browser) but a simple F5 will not always work.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can rely on the browser, but it may take a long time to wait for a `304` response. Google do it in a more efficient way. Each value of the cache-busting parameter `v` stands for a specific version of file. If you don't change that value, browsers will skip version validation and keep using the local cache indicated by `Cache-Control` or `Expires`.

So, it's a decision between performance and convenience.

CASE 2. If your file is not existed but created dynamically(i.e. merge some script files together in a real time), you need the parameter too.